# Force a child class to initialize a variable

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have a class `Foo` that has a field `_customObject` that must be initialized. I also have a class `Bar` that inherits from `Foo`:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected CustomObject _customObject;

    public Foo()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    // Other methods that use _customObject
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    // Constructor and other methods
}
```

I can not initialize the object `_customObject` in `Foo` because every child inherited contains a different child of `CustomObject`, so it must be initialized in every child class:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
    {
        _customObject = new CustomObjectInherited1();
    }
}


public class Baz : Foo
{
    public Baz()
    {
        _customObject = new CustomObjectInherited2();
    }
}
```

Other people are going to implement new classes that inherit from `Foo`, so I was wondering if there is a way that an error in build time is shown, similar to when an abstract method is not implemented. If `CustomObject` is not initialized, a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown due to the use of the  `_customObject` variable, ending in an application crash.

Comment: I think this is actually a great question. I suspect the downvote was due to the level it was asked at. But, in fact, even questions on simple concepts show a great effort and clarity of questioning. This is about improving design and I like it. +1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your `Foo` constructor:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected CustomObject _customObject;

    public Foo(CustomObject obj)
    {
        // Do stuff
        _customObject = obj;
    }
    // Other methods that use _customObject
}
```

Your derived classes will then be forced to call it, passing in a `CustomObject`, or something derived from it:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar():base(new CustomObjectInherited1())
    {

    }
}
```

Not calling the base constructor will result in a compile time error.  This doesn't entirely protect you, as someone could still pass `null` to the base constructor, but at least they'll have an explanation as to why they're getting a `NullReferenceError` at runtime.

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's fair. I just felt JayMee's answer better emphasized what the OP wanted to know.

Answer (score 7):

You can force it by creating a abstract method which requires child classes to override it.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected abstract CustomObject CreateCustomObject();
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override CustomObject CreateCustomObject()
    {
        return new BarCustomObject();
    }
}
```

Or my favorite solution: Enforce it by generic constraints.

```
public abstract class Foo<T> : where T : CustomObject, new()
{
    protected T _customObject;
    public Foo()
    {
        this.CustomObject = new T();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo<BarCustomObject>
{
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: I think the first part of this answer is the most correct, as it is more explicit in saying, "hey, you must do this". As most of the cost of a software product is in the maintenance of it over time, I am a fan of keeping it simple.

Comment: @JClark4321 There is no "more correct" in this case. I have used both ways depending which is more suitable to solve the current problem. The "best" answer would be to use an dependency injection with contextual binding, but that would only make sense if you already use an IOC container.

Comment: Both solutions work only if we know how will the constructor for `BarCustomObject` look like. I.e. which parameters will it have.

Comment: @Aldarrion Well, the initial question was `Force a child class to initialize a variable` Yes, this implies knowing how to initialize the variable, wither or not you enforce it. But you can easily delegate the task to an IOC container or use a factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by "James Thorpe" is correct (I've upvoted it already), but I wanted to share just another option here:
You could mark your class as abstract and introduce an abstract property instead of the "_customObject" field. That way, at least the first initializer will be forced to implement it. The downside is that you'll loose the enforcement on subsequent level subclasses:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected abstract CustomObject CustomObject {get; }

    public Foo()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    // Other methods that use _customObject
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    // Constructor and other methods

    protected override CustomObject CustomObject
    {
        get { return "X"; }
    }
}
```

Also, with the first solution it's possible to validate the passed in value in the constructor - though, that'll be a runtime validation.